# Annotating a ADT/Node tree with "parent" labels in Rascal

Tags: adt, rascal

I want to create a tree (using a `Node` or `ADT`) in which every node has an annotation pointing back to its parent. Below is an example with a simple linked list data structure:

```
import util::Math;
import IO;
import Node;

anno LinkedList LinkedList@parent;
anno int LinkedList@something;

data LinkedList = item(int val, LinkedList next)
                | last(int val)
                ;

public LinkedList linkedList =  item(5,
                                    item(4,
                                        item(3,
                                            item(2,
                                                last(1)[@something=99]
                                            )[@something=99]
                                        )[@something=99]
                                    )[@something=99]
                                )[@something=99];

public LinkedList addParentAnnotations(LinkedList n) {
    return top-down visit (n) {
        case LinkedList x: {
            /* go through all children whose type is LinkedList */
            for (LinkedList cx <- getChildren(x), LinkedList ll := cx) {
                /* setting the annotation like this doesn't seem to work */
                cx@parent = x;
                // DOESN'T WORK EITHER: setAnnotation(cx, getAnnotations(cx) + ("parent": x));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Executing `addParentAnnotations(linkedList)` yields the following result:

```
rascal>addParentAnnotations(linkedList);
LinkedList: item(
  5,
  item(
    4,
    item(
      3,
      item(
        2,
        last(1)[
          @something=99
        ])[
        @something=99
      ])[
      @something=99
    ])[
    @something=99
  ])[
  @something=99
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that Rascal data is immutable, so you can not update anything using an assignment. The assignment will simply give you a new binding for `cx` with the annotation set, but will not change the original tree.

To change the original tree, you can either use the `=>` operator for case statements, or the `insert` statement as follows:

```
 case LinkedList x => x[@parent=...] // replace x by a new x that is annotated
```

or:

```
 case LinkedList x : {
    ...
    x@parent= ...;
    insert x; // replace original x by new x in tree
 }
```

Some other tip, in the `Traversal.rsc` library you can find a function called `getTraversalContext()` which produces a list of parents of the currently visited node if called from the body of a case:

```
import Traversal;

visit (...) {
    case somePattern: {
        parents = getTraversalContext();
        parent = parents[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks very promising, except that I can't seem to import the Traversal module. It can't be found according to eclipse.

Comment: After a little researching I see a difference between the latest version of the git repository and the eclipse plugin. `Traversal.rsc` is not present in the eclipse plugin. I'm assuming the eclipse plugin from the update site does not have this feature yet. I tried installing the plugin from the "unstable" update site, but it fails: it requires `org.eclipse.jetty.http 8.1.3`, but it can't be found. I'm using eclipse 3.7 for RCP/RAP developers.

Comment: Problem solved, after installing eclipse Juno (4.2) for RCP/RAP developers. And I forgot to thank you for your solution. Helped me out very much, thanks!! Except now I get the root node as parent all the time, and any other index than -1 (e.g. 1 or -2). I need the direct parent of the currently evaluated node.

Comment: I see now how the traversal context is built up. I need index `1`, not `-1`. My solution: `if ([_, LinkedList parent, _*] := parents) { x@parent = parent; }`

Comment: Aha! I did not test the code I put here. Thanks for the fix. Can you mark the answer as accepted too? Cheers!

Comment: Something that I don't get yet, is why you need the match? Is that to account for empty parent lists?

Comment: I need the match to account for the top level item that does not have a parent (and only has 1 item in the parents list, namely itself, otherwise I get an "index out of bounds" exception when I use parents[1]). Thanks again!

Comment: You could say `parent = parents[ (size(parents) > 1) ? 1 : 0 ]` if you always want to get the immediate parent or, if there is none, the current node. Then you would not need the match.